# Solving a first order homogeneous differential equation with initial value

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do you solve the following differential equation?

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=(x+y)^2,\quad 
 y(0)=0$$

I know the answer is: $$y(x)=\frac{1}{c_1e^{2ix}-\frac{i}{2}}-x-i$$

But I don't know how to solve this can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $y=z-x$
$$y'=z'-1=(x+y)^2=z^2$$
This is a Riccati ODE : Let $z=-\frac{f'}{f}\quad \to \quad z'=-\frac{f''}{f}+\frac{f'^2}{f^2}$
$$z'-1=z^2=-\frac{f''}{f}+\frac{f'^2}{f^2}-1=\frac{f'^2}{f^2}$$
$$f''+f=0\quad \to \quad f=c_1\cos(x)+c_2\sin(x)$$
$z=-\frac{f'}{f}=-\frac{-c_1\sin(x)+c_2\cos(x)}{c_1\cos(x)+c_2\sin(x)}$
$$y=-\frac{-c_1\sin(x)+c_2\cos(x)}{c_1\cos(x)+c_2\sin(x)}-x$$
$y(0)=0= -\frac{c_2}{c_1}\quad \to \quad c_2=0\quad \to \quad y=\frac{c_1\sin(x)}{c_1\cos(x)}-x$
$$y=\tan(x)-x$$